# How to copy a variable in Ansible including undefined?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to pass variables from one role to another role.

So for example I'm using a meta dependency in my ntp role that pulls in timesync. Obviously I don't want to use variables of role ntp in my timesync role.

```
dependencies:
- role: timesync
  vars:
    timesyncd_servers: '{{ ntp_servers }}'
  when:
    - ntp_servers is defined
    - ntp_daemon == 'systemd'
```

If I'm now using a jinja test on `timesyncd_server` in my template file then it is defined (even if `ntp_servers` is undefined):

```
{% if timesyncd_servers is defined %}{{ timesyncd_servers }}{% endif %}
```

The problem now is that this if statement doesn't catch an undefined `ntp_servers` and ansible fails with `'ntp_servers' is undefined`.

I did try passing it with `| default(omit)` - that stopped ansible from failing, but the if statement still is true.

Any idea how to copy `ntp_servers` into `timesyncd_servers` so that it stays undefined?